# Running Visual Studio 2010 UI tests not on Ultimate

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have built a test with UI automation using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate. I would like to run the test on computers that have other editions of Visual Studio 2010 installed, not Ultimate. However when I try to use mstest\testcontainer:tests.dll (the dll file of the test with the debug library) there was error that it was missing one of the test files.

Is there a way to run a UI test on a computer without the Ultimate edition? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Coded UI Tests only run with VS **Ultimate** and VS **Premium**.

Here is an overview showing which VS edition supports which testing features: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products.

Here is the screenshot of the link above, just in case the URL shouldn't work anymore one day:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to the Coded UI tests, it's only available on the Ultimate or Premium versions of VS2010.  If a user is using the Express or Professional, they just won't be able to do it.

If upgrading those users to Ultimate/Premium isn't an option, you might want to look at a different UI testing tool.